# Shaded Multicols

Tags: color, multicol

Does anyone know how to shade the background and put a border around a `multicol` environment, where page breaks are needed.

There is a couple of posts around, most notably, [multicols within colorbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83779/multicols-within-colorbox), but there seems to be problems.

The best looking environment is the `tcolorbox`, but, cant do pagebreaks.

`mdframed` appears to overflow when pagebreaks are required (ie when `multicol` env. across multiple pages)

I really don't have an MWE, given the above comments RE `tcolorbox` and `mdframed`.

Comment: What about [Is it possible to define a multicolumn environment with a background colour](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50743/5764)?

Comment: In my previous answer, if you need a border (since the background is already fixed), you just have to change the color `colframe=white` from the `tcolorbox` version or `linecolor=white` in the `mdframed` version.

Comment: @Werner, Im getting errors with that solution. Im running Article, not memoir perhaps.

Comment: @Claudio. tcolor box is the best, but it cant pagebreak....

Comment: @ADP: I agree with you `:)`; my previous comment should be intended as a way to get the border that in the other question was not necessary. Notice, however, that in the solution suggested by Werner, the first example has `article` as `documentclass`: only the second goes under `memoir`.

Comment: @Werner aaaagh I wish I'd noticed your comment earlier. I had no recollection of having answered this before:(

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, David, thanks for this, not sure what has changed, but this code works fine now.... Many thanks...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You might want to play with the spacing a bit but something like this

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,color}

\makeatletter
\let\old@page@sofar\page@sofar
\let\old@box\box
\let\old@rlap\rlap
\def\page@sofar{%
\let\box\colorcolumn
\def\rlap{\let\box\old@box\old@rlap}%
\old@page@sofar
}
\def\colorcolumn#1{%
       \kern\dimexpr-\fboxrule-\fboxsep\relax
        {\let\box\old@box\fcolorbox{red}{yellow}{\box#1\llap{\phantom p}}}%
        \kern\dimexpr-\fboxrule-\fboxsep\relax
}

\makeatother


\def\a{Red blue green yellow black white. }
\def\b{One two three four five six. }
\def\c{\stepcounter{enumi} \Roman{enumi}
\a\a\b\b\a\a\b\a\a\b\b\b\b\b\b\a\a\b}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{3}
\c\c\c\c\c\c\c\c\c\c
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice. So you actually hook into `multicol`s "column output routine"?

Comment: yes @page@sofar is Frank's macro that lines up the boxes with the column text and inserts inter-column rules, This just patches it to add some colour at the same time.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle How could I put rounded corners on the outside corners on this?

Comment: `\fcolorbox{red}{yellow}{....}` is the standard (my) macro for butting colour behind a box, you can replace that by anything else that does the same but with more fancy features, tikz or tcolorbox or whatever.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If I want to apply this formatting to a duplicate environment (ie via \let\mymulticol\multicol and \let\myendmulticol\endmulticol), whilst retaining an unmodified version of the original, how is this possible, ie, how to distinguish the page@sofar, \box and \rlap commands between the duplicate and original environments.

Comment: @ADP change `\def\page@sofar{%` in the above to `\def\my@page@sofar{%` then by default the definition won't be used at all, but in the definition of your custom environment add `\let\page@sofar\my@pagesoofar` (in a package or after `\makeatletter`) then locally within your environment the new definition will be in effect and you will get shading.